# How to change the order of the panels in simple Lattice graphs

Tags: r, plot, lattice

Hi I am using the following code to generate an xyplot using lattice

```
xyplot(Rate~Weight|Temp, groups=Week, rate,
 pch=c(15,16,17,3), col=c("blue","red","green","purple"),
 as.table=TRUE,
 xlab="Weight (gr)", ylab="Rate (umol/L*gr)",
 main="All individuals and Treatments at all times",
 strip=strip.custom(strip.names=1),
 key=
 list(text=list(c("Week","1","2","6","8")),
 points=list(pch=c(NA,15,16,17,3),col=c(NA,"blue","red","green","purple")),
 space="right")
 )
```

This gives me the following plot:
[image]

Now after changing the code to include panel order as suggested:

```
xyplot(Rate~Weight|Temp, groups=Week, rate,
 index.cond=list(c(4,1,2,3)),#this provides the order of the panels
 pch=c(15,16,17,3), col=c("blue","red","green","purple"),
 as.table=TRUE,
 xlab="Weight (gr)", ylab="Rate (umol/L*gr)",
 main="All individuals and Treatments at all times",
 strip=strip.custom(strip.names=1),
 key=
 list(text=list(c("Week","1","2","6","8")),
 points=list(pch=c(NA,15,16,17,3),col=c(NA,"blue","red","green","purple")),
 space="right")
 )
```

and we get the correct order
[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: +1 for providing data and tried solution. Would be nicer if the data was in R-eady format (using `dput` or constructing a `data.frame`/`matrix` using `sample`, `runif`, `letters`...).

Comment: @Roman I included the working code and the graphs to ilustrate hope it helps :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I converted `Temp` to factor and got this:

[image]

You can temper with factor order like so:

```
levels(rate$Temp) <- c("12", "9", "18", "15") #custom factor order
```

Comment: @Roman Thanks!! such and easy solution, the one thing I did not try.

Comment: To clarify, lattice orders the panel based on the order of the factor, and when factors are created, by default, they're sorted first.  If you make a factor directly from the numeric variable, it will do what you want, but if you convert to a character first, it will sort alpha-numerically, which is what happened to you.

Comment: @Aron Thanks, needless to say I am not a programmer and I am new to both R and programming so I keep getting stuck with easy things. I was trying to used the index.cond with in the plot code but was getting nowhere.

Comment: @BDM, it gets easier with time. :)

Comment: @BDM Roman solution is better but this can be done with `index.cond`. Try `index.cond=list(c(4,1,2,3))`.

Comment: Thanks @Marek, I knew there was one clean way of doing it but was tight on time to look it up.

Comment: levels(rate$Temp) <- c("12", "9", "18", "15") will ***rename*** the levels not ***reorder*** them - right?